# Flutter flutter_bloc al hacer varias llamadas de red falla actualizar estado en los callbacks

Tags: flutter, callback, bloc

seguro muchos de ustedes ya saben como resolver pero yo no encuentro forma, estoy usando
Flutter 3.7.7,
flutter_bloc: ^8.1.2
package:http/http.dart'
La app esta desarrollada para android solamente por ahora.

Les comento:
Es para una aplicación de levantar pedidos offline y online.

El problema es el siguiente:
Tengo un bloc que contiene una lista de objetos en su estado.
Se puede levantar pedidos offline para que después cuando se quiera y tenga señal sincronizar con el server.

Vamos a suponer que se tiene 8 pedidos para enviar.
en cada item esta el boton "Enviar",
si uno le da click rapidamente a todos los botones, algunos pedidos quedan en error como si "no" se hubiese hecho la llamada al server (pero en realidad si se hizo).
Como **no actualiza el estado** de todos los objetos cuando uno presiona nuevamente para enviar los pedidos que fallaron, el server se queja que ese pedido que intentamos enviar ya fue creado. Los pedidos se identifican por un uuid que se crea de lado de la app.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta lo que les comento, en donde dice "Reenviar", "Enviando" se ha presentado el problema,
pero en realidad la llamada y la respuesta al server si se ha hecho y recibido,
pero al momento de hacer la actualización de estado falla,
seguro porque se esta haciendo varios cambios de estado seguidos y en algunos falla.
Si le doy de nuevo a Reenviar, falla porque ese uuid ya existe en el server, fijense donde dice (null)uuid. En donde esta null debiera estar el pedido_id.

Les pongo el event del bloc, que ejecuto cuando hago click.
cuando hago click al boton "Enviar" hago lo siguiente:
1.- Agrego un evento "OnSetCommunicatingWithServer" que modifica prop a pedido,  lo uso para actualizar ui.

```
  FutureOr<void> _onSetCommunicatingWithServer(
      SetCommunicatingWithServer event, Emitter<CartPedidosState> emit) {
    List<Pedido> pedidos = state.cart.pedidos;
    Pedido? pedido =
        pedidos.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element.uuid == event.uuid);
    if (pedido == null) {
      return null;
    }

    List<Pedido> newPedidos = [];
    pedido =
        pedido.copyWith(communicatingWithServer: event.value, errorString: '');
    for (var i in pedidos) {
      if (i.uuid != event.uuid) {
        newPedidos.add(i);
      }
    }

    emit(state.copyWith(cart: CartPedidos(pedidos: [...pedidos, pedido])));
  }
```

2.- despues de eso agrego "AddPedido"

```
void _onAddPedido(AddPedido event, Emitter<CartPedidosState> emit) async {
    CollectionBox cbox =
        await _localStorageRepository.openCollectionBox(DenBoxNameTypes.pedido);

    Pedido pedido = event.pedido;

    Pedido newPedido = pedido.copyWith(
      isInCloud: (pedido.pedidoId == null) ? false : true,
      isUpdatedInCloud: false,
      status: PedidoStatus.sinenviar,
      communicatingWithServer: false,
      errorString: '',
    );

    List<Pedido> listPedidos = [];
    for (var i in state.cart.pedidos) {
      if (i.uuid != event.pedido.uuid) {
        listPedidos.add(i);
      }
    }

    try {
      await _localStorageRepository.addPedido(cbox, newPedido);

      if (newPedido.isInCloud) {
        final uuidResp = await _pedidoRepository.putPedido(newPedido);
        if (uuidResp != null) {
          newPedido = newPedido.copyWith(
            uuid: uuidResp,
            isInCloud: true,
            isUpdatedInCloud: true,
            status: PedidoStatus.actualizado,
            communicatingWithServer: false,
            errorString: '',
          );
        }
      } else {
        final resp = await _pedidoRepository.postPedido(pedido);
        if (resp != null) {
          final int pedidoId = resp['pedido_id'];
          final String uuid = resp['uuid'];
          newPedido = newPedido.copyWith(
            uuid: uuid,
            pedidoId: pedidoId,
            isInCloud: true,
            isUpdatedInCloud: true,
            status: PedidoStatus.creado,
            communicatingWithServer: false,
            errorString: '',
          );
        }
      }
      _connectivityCubit.changeValidSession(true);
      if (event.callBack != null) {
        event.callBack!();
      }
    } on Unauthorized catch (e) {
      _connectivityCubit.changeValidSession(false);
      newPedido =
          newPedido.copyWith(errorString: '$e', communicatingWithServer: false);
    } catch (e) {
      newPedido =
          newPedido.copyWith(errorString: '$e', communicatingWithServer: false);
      //TODO descomentar get
      // add(GetPedidoFromServer(uuid: newPedido.uuid));
      rethrow;
    } finally {
      await _localStorageRepository.addPedido(cbox, newPedido);
      final List<Pedido> newArray = [...listPedidos, newPedido];
      add(
        UpdateCartPedidos(
          cart: CartPedidos(pedidos: newArray),
          loading: false,
          gettingFromServer: false,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

update cart pedidos

```
  void _onUpdateCartPedidos(
      UpdateCartPedidos event, Emitter<CartPedidosState> emit) {
    emit(state.copyWith(
        cart: event.cart,
        loading: event.loading,
        gettingFromServer: event.gettingFromServer));
    add(UpdateNotificationCubit());
  }
```

notification cubit

```
  FutureOr<void> _onUpdateNotificationCubit(
      UpdateNotificationCubit event, Emitter<CartPedidosState> emit) {
    final logger = Logger();
    logger.i('on update notificatrion cubit Pedidos on bloc');
    if (state.cart.pedidos.any((element) => element.esEditable)) {
      _notificationCubit.addNotificationByType(NotificationItem.newNotification(
          notificationType: NotificationType.pedidoNoCerrado,
          title: 'Tiene pedidos sin cerrar'));
    } else {
      _notificationCubit.removeNotificationbyType(
          notificationType: NotificationType.pedidoNoCerrado);
    }
  }
```

pedido model

```
    import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:denmob/den_constants_enums/den_constants_enums.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

import 'package:denmob/models/base_model.dart';
import 'package:denmob/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

import '../blocs/blocs.dart';
import 'models.dart';
import 'pedido_status.dart';

part 'pedido_model.g.dart';

// flutter packages pub run build_runner build
@HiveType(typeId: 5)
class Pedido extends Equatable with BaseModel {
  @HiveField(0)
  final String uuid;
  @HiveField(1)
  final int? pedidoId;
  @HiveField(2)
  final String fechaCreado;
  @HiveField(3)
  final String updatedAt;
  @HiveField(4)
  final int? idBackend;
  @HiveField(5)
  final String? fechaEntrega;
  @HiveField(6)
  final int? clienteId;
  @HiveField(7)
  final Map<int, PedidoItem> pedidoItems;
  @HiveField(8)
  final bool isUpdatedInCloud;
  @HiveField(9)
  final bool isInCloud;
  @HiveField(10)
  final double bonif;
  @HiveField(11)
  final String? observ;
  @HiveField(12)
  final PedidoStatus? status;
  @HiveField(13)
  final bool editable;
  @HiveField(14)
  final int? userId;
  @HiveField(15)
  final double montoDescMake;
  final bool communicatingWithServer;
  final String errorString;

  Pedido({
    required this.uuid,
    this.editable = true,
    this.pedidoId,
    required this.fechaCreado,
    required this.status,
    required this.updatedAt,
    this.idBackend,
    this.fechaEntrega,
    this.clienteId,
    this.pedidoItems = const {},
    this.isUpdatedInCloud = false,
    this.isInCloud = false,
    this.bonif = 0,
    this.observ,
    this.userId,
    this.communicatingWithServer = false,
    this.errorString = '',
    this.montoDescMake = 0,
  });

  int get getTsCreado => dateToTimestamp(fechaCreado);
  int get getTsUpdatedAt => dateToTimestamp(updatedAt);

  int get getTotalItemsLength => pedidoItems.length;

  bool get esEditable => editable && idBackend == null;

  bool get hasAnyOferta =>
      pedidoItems.values.any((element) => element.ofertaId != null);

  bool get hasDescMake =>
      pedidoItems.values.any((element) => element.hasDescMake);

  factory Pedido.updateProductsPedidoForCliente(Pedido pedido) {
    final ctx = NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentContext;

    Pedido newPedido = pedido.copyWith(pedidoItems: {});
    for (var pedidoItem in pedido.pedidoItems.values) {
      newPedido.addProduct(
        context: ctx!,
        productId: pedidoItem.productId,
        addQty: pedidoItem.qty,
      );
    }
    return newPedido;
  }

  double get totalProducts {
    final List<PedidoItem> listProducts =
        pedidoItems.values.where((element) => !element.hasOferta).toList();
    return listProducts.fold(
        0,
        (previousValue, pedidoItem) =>
            previousValue + (pedidoItem.precioItem * pedidoItem.qty));
  }

  double get totalOfertas {
    final List<PedidoItem> listOfertas =
        pedidoItems.values.where((element) => element.hasOferta).toList();
    // pedidoItems.values.where((element) => element.hasOferta && !element.product.especial ).toList();
    return listOfertas.fold(
      0,
      (previousValue, pedidoItem) =>
          previousValue + (pedidoItem.precioItem * pedidoItem.qty),
    );
  }

  double get total => (totalProducts + totalOfertas);
  bool get isNotEmpty => pedidoItems.isNotEmpty;
  int howManyProductsQtyById(int prodId) {
    return pedidoItems[prodId] != null ? pedidoItems[prodId]!.qty : 0;
  }

  PedidoItem? getPedidoItem(int prodId) {
    return pedidoItems[prodId];
  }

  bool hasProduct(int productId) {
    return pedidoItems.containsKey(productId);
  }

  @override
  copyFrom(element) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  Pedido setCommunicatingWithServer(
          Pedido pedido, bool value, String? errorString) =>
      pedido.copyWith(
        communicatingWithServer: value,
        errorString: errorString ?? '',
      );

  @override
  Pedido copyWith({
    String? uuid,
    int? pedidoId,
    int? idBackend,
    String? fechaCreado,
    String? fechaEntrega,
    int? clienteId,
    Map<int, PedidoItem>? pedidoItems,
    bool? isUpdatedInCloud,
    bool? isInCloud,
    double? bonif,
    int? userId,
    String? observ,
    PedidoStatus? status,
    bool? editable,
    String? updatedAt,
    bool? communicatingWithServer,
    String? errorString,
    double? montoDescMake,
  }) =>
      Pedido(
        uuid: uuid ?? this.uuid,
        pedidoId: pedidoId ?? this.pedidoId,
        idBackend: idBackend ?? this.idBackend,
        clienteId: clienteId ?? this.clienteId,
        fechaCreado: fechaCreado ?? this.fechaCreado,
        fechaEntrega: fechaEntrega ?? this.fechaEntrega,
        pedidoItems: pedidoItems ?? copyProductMap(this.pedidoItems),
        isUpdatedInCloud: isUpdatedInCloud ?? this.isUpdatedInCloud,
        isInCloud: isInCloud ?? this.isInCloud,
        bonif: bonif ?? this.bonif,
        observ: observ ?? this.observ,
        status: status ?? this.status,
        editable: editable ?? this.editable,
        updatedAt: updatedAt ?? this.updatedAt,
        userId: userId ?? this.userId,
        montoDescMake: montoDescMake ?? this.montoDescMake,
        communicatingWithServer:
            communicatingWithServer ?? this.communicatingWithServer,
        errorString: errorString ?? this.errorString,
      );

  int get fechaCreadoTimestamp => dateToTimestamp(fechaCreado);
  int get fechaUpdatedAtTimestamp => dateToTimestamp(updatedAt);

  Map<int, PedidoItem> copyProductMap(Map<int, PedidoItem> mapPedidoItems) {
    Map<int, PedidoItem> newMap = {};
    mapPedidoItems.forEach((key, value) => newMap[key] = value.copyWith());
    return newMap;
  }

  static List<Pedido> listFromJson(String str) =>
      List<Pedido>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Pedido.fromJson(x)));

  factory Pedido.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    late final PedidoStatus status;
    if (json['status'] != null) {
      status = PedidoStatus.creado;
    } else {
      status = json['editable'] == false
          ? PedidoStatus.cerrado
          : PedidoStatus.creado;
    }
    final p = Pedido(
      uuid: json['uuid'],
      pedidoId: json['pedido_id'],
      idBackend: json['id_backend'],
      clienteId: json['customer_id'],
      observ: json['observ'],
      fechaCreado: json['created_at'],
      fechaEntrega: json['fecha_entrega'],
      isInCloud: json['isInCloud'] ?? false,
      isUpdatedInCloud: json['isUpdatedInCloud'] ?? false,
      editable: json['editable'] ?? true,
      status: status,
      updatedAt: json['updated_at'],
      userId: json['user_id'],
    );
    return p;
  }

  factory Pedido.newPedido({
    int? clienteId,
    int? userId,
  }) =>
      Pedido(
        uuid: const Uuid().v4(),
        pedidoId: null,
        idBackend: null,
        fechaCreado: getDateTime(withHours: true),
        updatedAt: getDateTime(withHours: true),
        isUpdatedInCloud: false,
        isInCloud: false,
        clienteId: clienteId,
        status: PedidoStatus.desconocido,
        pedidoItems: const {},
        editable: true,
        userId: userId,
      );

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    //TODO: ver si esta bien escrito;
    throw Exception('Revisar toJson de pedido_model.dart');
  }

  static Map<int, Pedido> mapFromJson(String source) {
    try {
      List<dynamic> listJson = List<dynamic>.from(json.decode(source));

      Map<int, Pedido> pedidos = {
        for (var json in listJson) json.uuid: Pedido.fromJson(json)
      };
      return pedidos;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  void setObserv({String? observ}) {
    observ = observ;
  }

  double getTotalDescMake() {
    final ctx = NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentContext;

    final products = BlocProvider.of<ProductBloc>(ctx!).state.products;
    double tot = 0;
    for (var item in pedidoItems.values) {
      if (item.hasDescMake) {
        final product = products[item.productId];
        if (product != null) {
          tot += (item.precioItem * product.descMake / 100) * item.qty;
        }
      }
    }
    return tot * -1;
  }

  void setQtyPedidoItem({
    required BuildContext context,
    required int productId,
    required int newQty,
  }) {
    final product = UtilsProduct.getProducById(context, productId);
    if (product == null) {
      throw Exception('Error al leer producto $productId');
    }

    final currentPedidoItem = getPedidoItem(product.id);
    final oferta = UtilsOferta.getOfertaByProduct(context, product);

    if (currentPedidoItem == null && oferta == null) {
      pedidoItems[product.id] = PedidoItem(productId: product.id, qty: newQty);
    }

    final matchOferta = (oferta != null)
        ? (newQty >= oferta.qty && oferta.estaVigente && !product.especial)
        : false;

    final matchMake = product.clientPrice == product.price &&
        product.provId == DenContants.makeProvId &&
        product.descMake != 0 &&
        !matchOferta;

    double price = product.precioCliente;
    if (matchOferta) {
      price = oferta.bonif;
    } else if (matchMake) {
      price = product.price ?? 0;
    }

    pedidoItems[product.id] = (currentPedidoItem != null)
        ? currentPedidoItem.copyWith(
            ofertaId: matchOferta ? oferta.id : null,
            qty: newQty,
            hasDescMake: matchMake,
            precioItem: price,
          )
        : PedidoItem(
            productId: product.id,
            ofertaId: matchOferta ? oferta.id : null,
            precioItem: price,
            hasDescMake: matchMake,
            qty: newQty,
          );
  }

  void addProduct(
      {required BuildContext context, required int productId, int? addQty}) {
    int newAddQty = addQty ?? 1;
    final pedidoItem = getPedidoItem(productId);
    final actualQty = pedidoItem != null ? pedidoItem.qty : 0;

    setQtyPedidoItem(
        context: context, productId: productId, newQty: actualQty + newAddQty);
  }

  void removePedidoItem(PedidoItem pedidoItem) {
    removeProducto(pedidoItem.productId);
  }

  void removeOferta(Oferta oferta) {
    if (pedidoItems.containsKey(oferta.prodId)) {
      pedidoItems[oferta.prodId] =
          pedidoItems[oferta.prodId]!.copyWith(ofertaId: null);
    }
  }

  void removeProducto(int productId) {
    if (hasProduct(productId)) {
      pedidoItems.remove(productId);
    }
  }

  void addOferta({
    required BuildContext context,
    required Oferta oferta,
  }) {
    final product = UtilsProduct.getProducById(context, oferta.prodId);

    if (product == null) {
      return;
    }

    final pedidoItem = getPedidoItem(oferta.prodId);

    final qtyProduct = (pedidoItem != null) ? pedidoItem.qty : 0;
    final minQtyOferta = oferta.qty;
    setQtyPedidoItem(
      context: context,
      productId: product.id,
      newQty: qtyProduct != 0 ? qtyProduct + 1 : minQtyOferta,
    );
  }

  void setObservPedidoItem({required Product product, String? observ}) {
    PedidoItem? currentPedidoItem = getPedidoItem(product.id);
    if (currentPedidoItem != null) {
      pedidoItems[product.id] = currentPedidoItem.copyWith(observ: observ);
    }
  }

  @override
  String toString() => '''
        uuid: $uuid,
        pedidoId: $pedidoId,
        idBackend: $idBackend,
        clienteId: $clienteId,
        communicatingWithServer $communicatingWithServer,
        userId $userId,
        isUpdatedInCloud $isUpdatedInCloud,
        isInCloud: $isInCloud,
        fechaCreado $fechaCreado,
        fechaEntrega $fechaEntrega,
        pedidoItems $pedidoItems,
        bonif: $bonif,
        observ $observ,
        status $status,
        editable $editable,
        updatedAt $updatedAt,
        errorString $errorString,
        montoDescMake $montoDescMake,
''';

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        uuid,
        pedidoId,
        clienteId,
        idBackend,
        fechaCreado,
        fechaEntrega,
        pedidoItems,
        bonif,
        isInCloud,
        isUpdatedInCloud,
        observ,
        status,
        editable,
        updatedAt,
        userId,
        communicatingWithServer,
        errorString,
        montoDescMake,
      ];
}
```

Cart pedidos

```
import 'package:denmob/models/base_model.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

import 'models.dart';

part 'cart_pedidos_model.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class CartPedidos extends Equatable with BaseModel {
  @HiveField(0)
  final List<Pedido> pedidos;

  const CartPedidos({required this.pedidos});

  @override
  copyWith({
    List<Pedido>? pedidos,
  }) =>
      CartPedidos(
        pedidos: pedidos ?? this.pedidos,
      );

  factory CartPedidos.fromJson(List<dynamic> source) {
    List<Pedido> pedidos = [];
    try {
      for (var json in source) {
        pedidos.add(Pedido.fromJson(json));
      }

      return CartPedidos(pedidos: pedidos);
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [pedidos];

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  copyFrom(element) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Las llamadas y los callback pueden venir en desorden, porque son llamadas asíncronas,
Vuelvo a recalcar, que todas las llamadas si se hacen, y todas reciben respuestas, pero no en orden, el callback de la primera llamada puede venir despues del tercer get, y así.

En algunos callback no se ejecuta correctamente el cambio de estado.

Derrepente estoy haciendo las llamadas dentro del bloc y no debería, la inexperiencia no me deja ver que solución puedo dar a ese caso.

Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: puedes agregar tus clases UpdateCartPedidos, CartPedidos, Pedido ?

Comment: Hola @diegoveloper si claro, ya agregué, también hay otro que interviene _onUpdateNotificationCubit.

Desde ya gracias por tu ayuda